# implement method with second parameter set - introduction of implicit is unsupported

Tags: scala, implicit

I would like to understand why the following is not supported.

```
trait Y {
  def f(n: Int)(m: Int)
}
class S extends Y {
  override def f(n: Int)(m: Int): Unit = ???
}

class T extends Y {
  override def f(n: Int)(implicit m: Int): Unit = ???
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:18: error: class T needs to be abstract, since method f in trait Y of type (n: Int)(m: Int)Unit is not defined
       class T extends Y {
             ^
<console>:19: error: method f overrides nothing.
Note: the super classes of class T contain the following, non final members named f:
def f(n: Int)(m: Int): Unit
         override def f(n: Int)(implicit m: Int): Unit = ???
```

Comment: Because implicit method parameters are not overloadable with regular type parameters. You're breaking `Y`s signature.

Comment: I understand that, I would like to know the academic "why" of it

Comment: This are 2 different patterns cake pattern and implicits. Scala is already complicated as it is :)